# Поворот точки android

Tags: android, математика, canvas

Пытаюсь повернуть точку но в итоге всё двигается хаотично:
расстояние то увеличивается то уменьшается и двигаются постоянно,а должны поворачиваться на заданный угол

```
for (int i = 0; i < spotsAround.size() - 1; i++) {
            float x = Float.parseFloat(spotsAround.get(i).lat) - userLat;
            float y = Float.parseFloat(spotsAround.get(i).lon) - userLon;
            y *= kmLon;
            kmLat = (float) (Math.cos(Float.parseFloat(spotsAround.get(i).lon)))
                    * kmLon;
            x *= kmLat;

                    x *= getMeasuredWidth() / 2 / 0.5;
                    y *= getMeasuredHeight() / 2 / 0.5;
                
            
                double sinus=Math.sin(-direction); 
                double cosinus=Math.cos(-direction);

                x=(float) (x*cosinus-y*sinus); 
                y=(float) (x*sinus+y*cosinus);
            
            //canvas.rotate(degrees);
            
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(10);
            canvas.drawLine(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, 0, getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                    getMeasuredHeight(), paint);
            canvas.drawLine(0, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, getMeasuredWidth(),
                    getMeasuredHeight() / 2, paint);
        
    
                    canvas.drawBitmap(spot,((getMeasuredWidth() / 2) +
                             x)-spot.getWidth()/2,
                             ((getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - y)-spot.getHeight(), paint);
```

У меня есть геоданные спота и свои.В начале получаю координату где они вокруг меня находятся.Потом перевожу в км.Далее масштабирую под свою с.к. ,и поворачиваю.Далее рисую относительно центра экрана.Но всё летает туда сюда.Что не так то? при чём когда коанвас ротейт использую то всё правильно поворачивается

Answer (score 1):

Вообще не понятно зачем вам руками вычислять повороты, ну да ладно.

Но вообще ошибка тут:

```
x=(float) (x*cosinus-y*sinus); 
y=(float) (x*sinus+y*cosinus);
```

для `y` у вас `x` уже другой, что приводит к неправильному преобразованию. Надо как-то так:

```
x_new =(float) (x*cosinus-y*sinus); 
y_new =(float) (x*sinus+y*cosinus);
```

Вообще почитайте об [аффинных преобразованиях](http://topomatic.ru/reviews/46-Preobrazovanija-na-ploskosti-i-v-prostranstve).

Хотя, я бы на Вашем месте, разобрался бы как работать с матричными преобразованиями средствами самого canvas.